# Filter an array by comparing its property value with another array in angular/typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have two arrays

```
//1st one
tasks.push({ ID: 1, Address: "---", Latitude: 312313, Longitude: 21312 });
tasks.push({ ID: 3, Address: "---", Latitude: 312313, Longitude: 21312 });
//2nd one
agentTasks.push({ID:2,AgentID: 2,TaskID:1});
```

Now I want to filter `tasks` array to get only those values which are not included in `agentTasks` array. Like task id 1 is included in `agentTasks` but 3 is not included. So I want ID 3 value only. How can I do this in angular/typescript?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of all TaskIDs from `agentTasks` and then use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the `tasks` array to keep only those tasks which `ID` doesn't exist in the set of TaskIds:

```js
const tasks = [
  { ID: 1, Address: "---", Latitude: 312313, Longitude: 21312 },
  { ID: 3, Address: "---", Latitude: 312313, Longitude: 21312}
];
const agentTasks = [{ID:2,AgentID: 2,TaskID:1}];

const taskIds = new Set(agentTasks.map(({TaskID}) => TaskID));
const res = tasks.filter(({ID}) => !taskIds.has(ID));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I have get negative rating in this question and now i can't post any question. What should i do now?

Comment: @HunzlaSheikh you can take a look at this thread: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583)

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately you want to use the `filter` array function.

The simplest approach is to search the `agentTasks` array for each item in `tasks`. This is fine for small arrays, but inefficient for larger arrays.

Instead, I would create a `Map` from the `agentTasks` array, using `TaskID` as the key. You can then filter `tasks` based on whether or not they have a corresponding key in the `Map`.

```js
//1st one
const tasks = [];
tasks.push({ ID: 1, Address: "---", Latitude: 312313, Longitude: 21312 });
tasks.push({ ID: 3, Address: "---", Latitude: 312313, Longitude: 21312 });

//2nd one
const agentTasks = [];
agentTasks.push({ID:2,AgentID: 2,TaskID:1});

const agentTasksMap = new Map(agentTasks.map(x => [x.TaskID, x]));
const filtered = tasks.filter(task => !agentTasksMap.has(task.ID));

console.log(filtered);
```

Edit: The answer using `Set` is better, since you don't care about the values in the `Map` in my answer - you only care about the existence of a key.

Comment: A keyed array, effectively. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map. `Set` from the other answer is better though, since you only care about the keys, not the values.